# How to store class attribute information in a list when creating an object?

Tags: python, list, class

I am trying to find a way to store class attribute information in a list when the object is created. I am just learning python classes and am having some difficulty figuring out how to implement the **str** method correctly.

```
    muffins = []
    
    class Muffin:
        def __init__(self,name,calories):
            self.name = name
            self.calories = calories
            muffins.append(Muffin)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
    
    banana_chocolate_chip = Muffin('banana_chocolate_chip', 250)
    
    blueberry = Muffin('blueberry', 200)
    
    pumpkin_pecan = Muffin('pumpkin_pecan', 225)
    
    
    for muffin in muffins:
        print(muffin)
```

When I run this code I get:

```
    <class '__main__.Muffin'>
    <class '__main__.Muffin'>
    <class '__main__.Muffin'>
```

My desired output is:

```
    banana_chocolate_chip
    blueberry
    pumpkin_pecan
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use muffins.append(self) instead of muffins.append(Muffin) to get your desired output. muffins.append(Muffin) doesn't append an actual instance of the muffin class, passing self will refer to the instance that just got created.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense! Thanks